# Need Help Accessing Properties in Enclosing Class from Sub Class

Tags: c#, subclass

I am having problems. I have a subclass based on Randy Patterson's fluent interface example here:

[Randy Patterson's Fluent Interface Design Page](http://randypatterson.com/index.php/2007/09/26/how-to-design-a-fluent-interface/)

I am subclassing a User class and need to pass the properties set in it to the below CreateNewUser method within the UserFluentInterface subclass.

```
public void CreateNewUser()
              {

                    try
                    {
                        User user = (User)_User;

                        MembershipCreateStatus status;
                        MembershipUser memuser = _membership.CreateUser(user, out status);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        string message = e.Message;
                    }

                }
```

and _membership.CreateUser has the signature:

```
public MembershipUser CreateUser(User user, out MembershipCreateStatus status);
```

I am getting the error:

> Cannot access a non-static member of
>   outer type 'MyProject.Schema.User' via
>   nested type
>   'MyProject.Schema.User.UserFluentInterface'

I am not sure how resolve this. Code is as follows:

```
User user = _someAPI.GetUserProfile(txtEmail.Text);

user.Set
  .Email(txtEmail.Text)
  .Password(txtPassword.Text)
  .CreateNewUser();
```

Now, I have a User class with a subclass:

```
 public class User : ProfileBase, ISessionMgrEntry
    {
        MyMembershipProvider _membership = null;
        UserFluentInterface _set = null;

        public User()
        {
            _membership = (MyMembershipProvider)Membership.Providers["MyMembershipProvider"];
            _set = new UserFluentInterface(this);
        }

        public UserFluentInterface Set
        {
            get { return _set; }
        }

        #region ProfileBase Members

            [SettingsAllowAnonymous(false), CustomProviderData("Email;string")]
            public string Email { get { return base["Email"] as string; } set { base["Email"] = value; } }

[SettingsAllowAnonymous(false), CustomProviderData("Password;string")]
            public string Password { get { return base["Password"] as string; } set { base["Email"] = value; } }


           public class UserFluentInterface
            {
                private readonly User _User;

                public UserFluentInterface(User User)
                {
                    _User = User;
                }

                public UserFluentInterface Email(string email)
                {
                    _User.Email = email;
                    return this;
                }

                public UserFluentInterface Password(string password)
                {
                    _User.Password = password;
                    return this;
                }

                public void CreateNewUser()
                {

                    try
                    {
                       User user = ???? // HOW DO I ACCESS THE PROPERTIES THAT WERE ORIGINALLY SET AND PASS THEM AS AN OBJECT BELOW?                        

                        MembershipUser memuser = _membership.CreateUser(user);

                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        string message = e.Message;
                    }

                }

            }

       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're going to have to pass both user and membership into your UserFluentInterface:

```
            public class UserFluentInterface
            {
                private readonly User _User;
                private readonly Membership _Membership;

                public UserFluentInterface(User User, Membership membership)
                {
                    _User = User;
                    _Membership = membership;
                }
            }
```

and then use _Membership instead of _membership. in your CreateNewUser() method

Answer (score 0):

You can just write `User user = _User`, if  you don't need a copy of `_User`.

Otherwise, make a copy of `_User` and pass it on.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I tried that but keep getting
the following error (hence the post):

Cannot access a non-static member of outer type 'MyProject.Schema.User' via nested type 'MyProject.Schema.User.UserFluentInterface'

Any thoughts?

Comment: Read this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/nested_csclasses.aspx

Basically it means you cannot access members of User in UserFluentInterface. 

However, you can access those members in UserFluentInterface via the `_User` object, like `_User.Email`, not just `Email`.

I think you'd better post the full code for `UserFluentInterface` to see where exactly this error occurs.

Comment: Hi. Thanks again. There isn't much more to the UserFluentInterface class except for a bunch more getter and setters that really have nothing to do with the problem. I have posted a link to where I am getting the code if that is helpful. If you still feel the need for the code dump let me know and I will do it. I have also posted the CreateNewUser class up top as that is where the error is being thrown. it has something to do with the line _membership.CreateNewUser and "_memberhip" is what intellisense complains about. I am really stuck here.. help much appreciated. Thanks again.

Comment: Using just _User doesnt work, just like in your Password and Email methods?   (MembershipUser memuser = _membership.CreateUser(_User);)